# Why is my caching mechanism not working as expected?

Tags: android, caching, concurrency

I'm thoroughly stumped by this one.  I have a static class which manages a cache of downloaded bitmap images.  This class is accessed by multiple threads with potential for concurrent access.  Here's the implementation:

```
public class BitmapCache {
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER_BITMAPS_TO_CACHE = 30;
    private static Map<String, Bitmap> bitmapCache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
    private static List<String> cachedBitmapUrlsOrder = new ArrayList<String>();

    private BitmapCache(){}

    public static synchronized void addBitmapToCache(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmapCache.size() >= MAX_NUMBER_BITMAPS_TO_CACHE) {
            Log.i("MyApp", "Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = " + bitmapCache.size());
            String oldestUrl = cachedBitmapUrlsOrder.remove(0);
            bitmapCache.remove(oldestUrl);
        }
        bitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
        cachedBitmapUrlsOrder.add(url);
    }

    public static int size() {
        return bitmapCache.size();
    }

    public static Bitmap get(String url) {
        return bitmapCache.get(url);
    }

    public synchronized static void clearCache() {
        bitmapCache.clear();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a rolling cache so that when the max cache size is reached (a common occurence) the oldest bitmap is removed from the cache.  Running my application gives the following output:

```
02-29 23:00:26.590: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 30
02-29 23:00:26.600: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 30
02-29 23:00:26.720: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 30
02-29 23:00:26.790: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 30
02-29 23:00:26.820: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 31
02-29 23:00:26.850: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 31
02-29 23:00:27.050: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 32
02-29 23:00:27.070: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 32
02-29 23:00:27.100: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 33
02-29 23:00:27.130: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 34
02-29 23:00:27.170: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 35
02-29 23:00:27.210: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 35
02-29 23:00:27.330: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 35
02-29 23:00:27.360: I/MyApp(10789): Max cache size reached.  Removing oldest bitmap.  Size = 35
```

The code correctly starts logging 'Max cache size reached' when the cache size reaches 30 and stays there for a few executions.  But then it strangely begins to increase up to 35.  At this point it stays there for hundreds more output.  I can't get it to increase beyond 35.

What is wrong with my implemention?  Given the `addBitmapToCache` method is synchronized I'm baffled at how the cache size can grow beyond the maximum set.

Comment: In Jave, when you do .remove(0), does it automatically shift the rest of the items down for you?

Comment: According to javadoc it does...

Comment: Maybe worth logging the size again after removing from the map to make sure an item has really been removed?

Comment: @assylias, good catch.  At each point where the cache increases beyond 30 by one step, ``bitmapCache.remove(oldestUrl)`` is failing to remove the item from the cache.  Any ideas how this could happen?

Comment: I think Graham had a very good point about duplicates. It does not look like there are concurrrncy issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems.

Firstly, `cachedBitmapUrlsOrder` is a `List`. What happens to it if the same bitmap is requested more than once? You get a whole bunch of duplicate URLs in the list. So the first time you hit the limit, you remove a URL from the list, and from the map. **But the same URL is still in the list, with no matching map entry**. So subsequent attempts to remove the same URL from the list will **not** remove anything from the map, and the map will grow.

You can avoid this by checking, right at the start of `addBitmapToCache()`, if the URL is already cached, with `bitmapCache.containsKey(url)`. If so, you don't need to modify the map; just make sure this entry is remembered as the most recent.

Alternatively, change the list to be a collection of *unique* values; probably a map of URLs to timestamps, or a Set. (I'll let you decide.)

Also, the `get()` and `size()` methods should be synchronized too.

And `get()` should update the timestamp of the retrieved entry, so that it becomes the most recent.

Comment: Agree on why it is growing but wouldn't it be easiest to just add a line at the start of the add to cache method that checks map.containsKey(url) ?

Comment: @cotton.m Yes, added that to my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition Graham's answer, if the call is made to `clearCache` the `cachedBitmapUrlsOrder` does not get cleared. So when you next time reach a limit you will not be removing anything here:

```
String oldestUrl = cachedBitmapUrlsOrder.remove(0);
bitmapCache.remove(oldestUrl); // bitmapCache does not have such key
```

Comment: Another great catch.  Clearly its back to Developer 101 for me.